# Java Filter userinput problems

Tags: java

I am trying to make battleship. Here i want to get input from the console with a `Scanner` to determain a place to shoot.

```
while (x) {
    while (counter) {
        userInput = input.nextLine();
        if (userInput.equals("cheat")) {
            cheat = true;
        }

        uppercased = userInput.toUpperCase();
        char[] c = uppercased.toCharArray();

        if (uppercased.length() < 2) {
            System.out.println("Error, invalid input9, try again");
            break;
        } else if (uppercased.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Error, invalid input1, try again");
            break;
        } else if (uppercased.length() > 2) {
            System.out.println("Error, invalid input2, try again");
            break;
        } else if (c[0] < 65 || c[0] > 74) {
            System.out.println("Error, invalid input3, try again");
            break;
        } else if (c[1] < 48 || c[1] > 57) {
            System.out.println("Error, invalid input4, try again");
            break;
        } else {
            code = uppercased;
            target = map.get(uppercased);
            targetPosition = target.getSymbol();
            if (targetPosition != 46) {
                System.out.println("You have shot here, try again");
                break;
            }
        }
        counter = false;

    }
    x = false;
    code = uppercased;
}
```

the problem is, when I give a wrong input, it doesn't ask about new input, but it will execute the rest of my program.

It is supposed to filter input so it is like this:
"A1"
than it is used to determain a place to shoot.
How can I filter the wrong input and get new input?

Comment: Hint: Go read up on what `break` statements do.

Comment: Could you please describe what this code is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

- using `break`, will move you outside of  current loop.
- using `continue`, will move you to the beginning of current loop.

So in your case continue  would be better, because it will move you to part of code where you are reading input in inner loop.

Extracting main body from this loop (like below) would also be easy to test:)

Update:

```
while (x) {
    while (!runCheck()) { Your main method is extracted from loop, making it more readable
    }
    x = false;
    code = uppercased;
}

boolean runCheck(){
        userInput = input.nextLine();
        if ("cheat".equals(userInput)) { // prefer to compare String agains a constant in this way, it's immune to NPE, when by any chance userInput would be a null
            cheat = true;
        }

        uppercased = userInput.toUpperCase();
        char[] c = uppercased.toCharArray();

        if (uppercased.length() < 2) {
            System.out.println("Error, invalid input9, try again");
            return true;
        } else if ("".equals(uppercased)) {
        ...
        } else {
            code = uppercased;
            if(!map.conainsKey(uppercased)){ // target can be null, or not existing in map
               return true;
            }
            target = map.get(uppercased);
            targetPosition = target.getSymbol();
            if (targetPosition != 46) {
                System.out.println("You have shot here, try again");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I would also recommend to extract inner loop to a function that returns boolean, which tells us if this loop should or should not execute again, code would be more readable:)